# JSON-API pass in serializer class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using a gem called `jsonapi-rb`

I have a controller which eventually calls

```
render jsonapi: some_obj,
class: SomeSerializer,
include: :items
```

`SomeSerializer` has a `has_many` relationship that looks like such

```
has_many :items, class: ItemSerializer do
  linkage always: true
end
```

Is there a way that I can pass in `ItemSerializer` as a variable so that I can change it depending on certain conditions.

For example, I may want to use `ItemSerializerII` instead if some condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`has_many` is executed at class initialization so it won't get re-executed.

You can sort of do this at runtime

In the `SomeSerializer` create a method...

```
class self.build_items_association(klass)
  has_many :items, class: klass do
    linkage always: true
  end
end
```

Then you would do...

```
SomeSerializer.build_items_association(ItemSerializer)
render jsonapi: some_obj,
class: SomeSerializer,
inculde: :items
```

Or...

```
SomeSerializer.build_items_association(ItemSerializerII)
render jsonapi: some_obj,
class: SomeSerializer,
inculde: :items
```

This works with vanilla ActiveModel, I haven't tried it with your gem but I would imagine it'll work.